# Persistance of ApplicationInfo objects

Tags: android, caching, persistence

I am building an Android application that gets a List of all the applications installed on the device (ApplicatioInfo objects). Unfortunately, this process is too slow (about 10 seconds for 200 applications).

Is there a way to persist/cache my List<ApplicationInfo> across uses of my application?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can save it on the SharedPreferences of your app for a while:

```
ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> ai = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

//Add the apps to the ArrayList

JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(ai);

settings = getSharedPreferences("apps", 0);
settings.edit()
.putString("appList", ja.toString())
.putLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
.commit();
```

And then just check with a Timer or onResume method if the last list created was too old.

Comment: After retreiving the cache JSON string from shared prefs, how can I turn it back into an ArrayList of ApplicationInfo?

Comment: Probably you can iterate the JSONArray to add elements in the ArrayList

Comment: Hey, I'm getting a ClassCastException when I'm trying to cast the result from ja.get(index) to an ApplicationInfo. Any idea why?

Comment: I took a different approach and created a new class, AppDescriptor, that only holds the information I need about each ApplicationInfo object. I'm now using serialization to cache the AppDescriptor objects.